# why D's variant seems confusing

Tags: d, dynamic-typing

I experiment with the D language, and find the std.variant cool.

But then I find it confusing.

For example,

```
import std.stdio;
void main()
{
  string x = "";
  x ~= 'v';
  writeln(x);
}
```

This does what is expected.

But this,

```
import std.stdio;
import std.variant;
void main()
{
  Variant x = "";
  x ~= 'v';
  writeln(x);
}
```

gives a hard-to-decipher RUNTIME error.

Why is that?

Here is the message.

```
std.variant.VariantException@std/variant.d(1675): Variant: attempting to use incompatible types char and immutable(char)[]
----------------
??:? inout @property inout(immutable(char)[]) std.variant.VariantN!(32uL).VariantN.get!(immutable(char)[]).get() [0x106f84654]
??:? long std.variant.VariantN!(32uL).VariantN.handler!(immutable(char)[]).handler(std.variant.VariantN!(32uL).VariantN.OpID, ubyte[32]*, void*) [0x106f7559d]
??:? std.variant.VariantN!(32uL).VariantN std.variant.VariantN!(32uL).VariantN.opOpAssign!("~", char).opOpAssign(char) [0x106f84a1d]
??:? _Dmain [0x106f74d8d]
```

Comment: Please consider including the error message, so that we may be able to decypher it. Unwritten it is even harder, for me at least :-)

Comment: @StephaneRolland ok.

Comment: Never done any D tutorial. I may be wrong, but as it's created by one of the most influent C++ programmer A Alexandrescu, I read the message with a C++ mindset. The error message seems to say: "hey you give me a simple `char`, when I only work with an array of constant char that I call `immutable char`.

Comment: Moreover, I am totally puzzled by your usage of the operator `~=`. What does it mean in D? The introductionary page: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/d/ does not even mention this operator. In C++ there's  ~ for negating binary values... but I am wondering how useful could be a `~=` operator.

Comment: @StephaneRolland I think "~" means string concat, so "~=" means concat in place. I read somewhere that D has a Variant type, which makes it feels like a "dynamic" language, but when I played with it, I found it somehow blowed up with the "~=" operator. I tried change the char type to immutable char, and indeed the error is gone. I am still curious why the Variant type refuses the char type version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a bug in std.variant.Variant. The problem here is `char` and `immutable(char)` are two different types, and `Variant` doesn't know that they're closely related. There are two different workaround to this: Either make `x` hold a `char[]` instead of `immutable(char)[]` (also known as `string`), or make `'v'` an `immutable(char)`:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.variant;
void main()
{
  Variant x = "".dup; // Duplicate the string to make it a heap-allocated, mutable string.
  x ~= 'v';
  writeln(x);
}
```

or

```
import std.stdio;
import std.variant;
void main()
{
  Variant x = "";
  x ~= cast(immutable)'v'; // Make 'v' explicitly immutable.
  writeln(x);
}
```